# Loops de Stata en R

Tags: r, bucles

Hola a todos soy un usuario de Stata nuevo en `R`, estoy intentando hacer un `loop` en `R` pero no encuentro la forma.

Este loop lo que hace es reemplazar los valores missing por 0 en las variables... m1_2019ext m1_2019nacmay y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a m12_2019men.

Mi idea no es aprender a reemplazar los missings en particular sino como hacer el bucle anidado en `R` en general. ya que lo voy a tener que utilizar en varias ocasiones.

Así lo tengo hecho en Stata:

```
qui forval i = 1/12 {
        foreach j in ext nacmay rprov rloc est jp men {
        replace m`i'_2019`j' = 0 if m`i'_2019`j'==.
        }
}
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido FGB a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Seguramente conseguirás respuestas más fácilmente si explicas que es lo que hace el código de `sata`

Answer (score 0):

Señalemos algunas diferencias

1. Missing Values, en `R` se los conoce como `NA`
2. Uso de bucles, `R` está "acostumbrado" a trabajar con datos multidimensionales, por lo que, en general no es tan necesario recurrir a ciclos y en el caso de tu pregunta, ciertamente no.

Imagino que tienes un `data.frame`, llamado, por ejemplo: `m1_2019`, con varias columnas o variables, a las que le deseas reemplazar los `NA` por `0`, esto sería algo así:

```
columnas <- c("ext","nacmay","nrprov","nrloc","nest","jp men")
m1_2019[,columnas][[is.na(m1_2019[, columnas])] <- 0
```

Básicamente: (1) creamos un vector con las columnas que vamos a modificar, solo para escribir un poco menos (2) Solo en estas columnas, y solo en el caso de los valores `NA` los reemplazamos por `0`.

Como puedes observar, nada de ciclos, esto por que las funciones de selección `[]` o `is.na()` se dice que ya son vectorizadas. Es importante si vas a profundizar en este lenguaje, olvidarse de la idea de los ciclos, muy rara vez, los llegas a necesitar realmente. De cualquier manera, con un ciclo, el código sería algo así:

```
for (col in columnas)) {
  m1_2019[, col][is.na(m1_2019[, col])] <- 0
}
```

Puedes ver que es parecido al código anterior, salvo que en este caso iteramos por cada columna, entiendo que en el código SATA, además se itera por filas, en ese caso sería otro `for` pero por número de fila y hay que ajustar la asignación, para usar este dato, pero es todo un trabajo innecesario en `R`.